# Why is the client not receiving the socket.io broadcast (rooms)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

My client is not receiving the broadcast sent to the room. If I replace `socket.to(roomName).emit('join', currentUser);` with `socket.emit('join', currentUser);` the client receives the broadcast, but I'd like to use rooms here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`app.js`

```js
// Game
app.get('/game', (req, res) => {
    const cookies = req.cookies;
    const currentUser = cookies['current_user'];
    const roomName = cookies['room_name'];

    if (roomName) {
        res.render('pages/game', {
            room: roomName
        });

        io.of('/game').on('connection', socket => {
            console.log('a user connected');
            socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                console.log('user disconnected');
            });

            socket.join(roomName);

            socket.to(roomName).emit('join', currentUser);
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

`game.ejs`

```js
const socket = io("/game");

socket.on('join', function(user) {
    console.log(`${user} joined`);
});
```

Also, could I replace this:

```js
if (roomName) {
    // stuff
} else {
    // other stuff
}
```

with this:

```js
if (!roomName) {
    // other stuff
    return;
}
// stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/rooms/), if you use `socket.to('room').emit(...)` instead of `io.in('room').emit(...)`, it will be broadcasted to all sockets in the room **except the sender**. That's where your problem lies.

The reason `socket.emit(...)` works is because you're sending it directly and **only** to the sender.

This [emit cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emit-cheatsheet/index.html) is quite useful to figure out which combinations of `io`/`socket` and `to` etc affect where messages get sent to.

Comment: I replaced `socket.to(roomName).emit('join', currentUser);` with both `io.to(roomName).emit('join', currentUser);` and `io.in(roomName).emit('join', currentUser);`, but neither seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: My original `io.to(roomName)` was wrong and had to be `io.in`, as you seem to have spotted. It also seems that since you're using a namespace, you might have to even use `io.of('/game').to(roomName).emit(...)`. Cheatsheet is using `to` for that latter example instead of `in`, maybe it's just an alias. I'm also not sure whether it's `.of('/game')` or `.of('game')`.

Comment: Yep, using `io.of('/game').in(roomName).emit('join', currentUser);` worked. And `to` and `in` are aliases, according to the [docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/rooms/). Thanks for the help!